# ${n \choose m}$ on periodic lattice (Bravais)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, discrete-mathematics, algorithms

How can I generate all symmetry-inequivalent selections of m sites on a periodic 2d (Bravais) lattice with n sites?

Are there some general results or theorems which may be useful in this type of problem?

Comment: If you are looking for a computational solution, something like [*nauty*](http://pallini.di.uniroma1.it) could help.